# Parameterized update query is not working in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameterized-query

I am trying to update details but the query is not working. client id is auto-generated.
here is my code

```
try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand updatecmd = new SqlCommand();
            updatecmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           // long client_id = CreateID();
            updatecmd.CommandText= "UPDATE client_info SET companyname = @companyname, url = @url, industry = @industry, contactperson1 = @contactperson1, contactperson2 = @contactperson2, designation = @designation, fax = @fax, phone = @phone, mobile = @mobile, emailid1 = @emailid1, emailid2 = @emailid2, baddress = @baddress, bcity = @bcity, bstate = @bstate, bzipcode = @bzipcode, bcountry = @bcountry, regaddress = @regaddress, regcity = @regcity, regstate = @regstate, regzipcode = @regzipcode, regcountry = @regcountry WHERE client_id = @client_id";
           // updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_id", client_id);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyname", txtcompanyname.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", txturl.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@industry", drpindustry.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactperson1", txtcontactperson1.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactperson2", txtcontactperson2.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", txtdesignation.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", txtfaxnumber.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtphone.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", txtmobile.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailid1", txtemailid1.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailid2", txtemailid2.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@baddress", txtbaddress.InnerText);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bcity", txtbcity.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bstate", txtbstate.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bzipcode", txtbzipcode.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bcountry", bddlCountries.Text);

updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regaddress",txtraddress.InnerText);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regcity", txtrcity.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regstate", txtrstate.Text);

          updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regzipcode",txtrzipcode.Text);
            updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regcountry", 
            rddlCountries.Text);
            updatecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Its not showing error and exception but data is not stored in DB.

Comment: why client_id is in remark?

Comment: Could it be that you wanted to insert *new* data and not update *existing* data?

Comment: I dont want to update client_id

Comment: @fubo it doesn't matter, its in the where clause

Comment: @OfirWinegarten just noticed - `WHERE client_id = @client_id` doesn't work

Comment: You should provide client_id. Any reason it is commented in code?

Comment: Are you trying to insert a new row (as suggested by the CreateID function) or update an existing row? You need to use `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE` to insert a new row. Note that ExecuteNonQuery will return an integer of the number of rows affected, which you can check to make sure that a row was inserted or updated as expected.

Comment: @Dan Guzman I want to update the existing data with respect to the client_id as it is unique and I wont be changing that and I have insert query as well its working fine. I am facing issue with update query.

Comment: @Nirmala you should provide the client_id for which you would like its record updated

Comment: What is in your `catch` block, because this should definitely throw an error as you are not adding the `@client_id` parameter to the command.

Comment: You should provide all the parameters while using Parameterized query. As you are not passing client_id it wont work. Try passing client_Id and it will update the records respective to that id.

Comment: I tried adding client_id still its not working

Comment: @Crowcoder here is my catch block catch (Exception d)
        {
            string message = "update error";
            message += d.Message;
        }

Comment: That catch does nothing. You will never know an exception happened unless you are debugging and you have a break point in there.

Comment: @Nirmala, no error will be raised if the client_id is not found during the update. Check that the passed client_id actually exists and the count of rows updated is 1.